# mod_rewrite and "pretty urls"

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, seo

I'm woefully underequipped to use mod_rewrite for clean, SEO-friendly urls, but I am really determined to learn. I've found various online tutorials but can't seem to really understand the information enough to manipulate it the way I'd like.

```
I have a home page: http://mysite.com/index.html

which I would like to display as: http://mysite.com/home
```

And similarly, I have sub directories:

```
http://mysite.com/about/index.html
http://mysite.com/contact/index.php
Which I would like to display as 
http://mysite.com/about
and http://mysite.com/contact
```

**AND a gallery section of different products, each with a unique page, for instance:**

```
http://mysite.com/products/happybunnies.html OR
http://mysite.com/products/sillytigers.html
That I want to display as:
http://mysite.com/products/happy-bunnies/ AND
http://mysite.com/products/silly-tigers/
```

The last one is the most important to me. If anyone can find the generosity to explain:

1. What the entire .htaccess file looks like, including any necessary opening and closing tags before actually writing the code
2. The mod_rewrite code that takes "happybunnies.html" and makes it "happy-bunnies". AND any necessary information inside the html file that allows that to happen. (I see content like "name=" in urls, but I don't understand where to put that in the file)

I feel like it is simple, but I'm just missing a better understanding of it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =m=1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/index.html
RewriteRule ^.* /home? [R=301]
RewriteRule ^home /index.html?m=1 [QSA]
```

Give this a go and see how it works for you